# phpmyadmin import csv file, blank page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am importing csv files to phpmyadmin database. Some files ends up with blank page of phpmyadmin. It does not show me if it was succesful or if there is an error. Everything in the file seems ok but i cannot be sure because it doesnt show me anything.The size of file is much smaller than size of file that can be imported. What do i do with this problem ? It looks like this.. [image]
[sample of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK16b.png)

```
baby_snow_angel09@seznam.cz:krista
aldrine_ayay@seznam.cz:12345678
jpitalianrose@seznam.cz:123456
mckin0725@seznam.cz:picolo
jamvr10@seznam.cz:f3468d5
trawleonard@seznam.cz:OdmWjW9l
j1iyzinka@seznam.cz:4171817
hagenowdirk@seznam.cz:meiner
upossibilities@seznam.cz:believe1
noooooo_slleep_93@seznam.cz:guarana
hoyaesq@seznam.cz:048ab4cb8ae8f02a34377d2271adfea813.03.09
pesimist_88_1905@seznam.cz:345003425
stvtomo2@seznam.cz:sexonlegs
momsfavoritedaughter@seznam.cz:sparkles
intex64@seznam.cz:lasara
david350f@seznam.cz:pete11
brandilee@seznam.cz:DP44
toastntea@seznam.cz:goodhope
senchenko_anton@seznam.cz:demon1234
btkaplan@seznam.cz:baseball
femieniola@seznam.cz:inifika12
johnjohny123@seznam.cz:warrior1
rfparker0130@seznam.cz:Hollister5377
gabeess@seznam.cz:springsnow
mariaparisrealty@seznam.cz:courtney30
hiredgoon75@seznam.cz:2526824
TBerger815@seznam.cz:arbogast
dannytshort1@seznam.cz:green123
sadlimouloud@seznam.cz:mooky29700
cm.cvs_s@seznam.cz:mert3344
billnascar24@seznam.cz:cygnus24
lalafree@seznam.cz:littlecat
tcluke55@seznam.cz:TCmonster1
buharest@seznam.cz:615115
lilcarissa21@seznam.cz:bb7aedfa61007447dd6efaf9f37641e3
vrnnstar@seznam.cz:tx77014
yarik-80@seznam.cz:scorpion82
ctha187kid@seznam.cz:compaq23
```

Comment: Please show us a sample of the file and the table structure

Comment: @RohitGupta table has only two columns, email and password. there is a sample of file http://leteckaposta.cz/628253684

Comment: You need to post it here.  Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RohitGupta ok i edited question there is an image of file

Comment: Please post text information as text, not as an image.  Otherwise there is very little chance anyone will want to click on a link to look at it.  And it they want to try the code, they have to type it in !!!!

Comment: @RohitGupta i get it. The file looks like this, there are 3,5 milions lines in it. I already tried eliminate mistakes in file which could cause the problem, but blank page keeps showing up.

Comment: Maybe particular values are causing it.  Maybe you can do a binary trim on them.  Try each half.  And then repeat with the half that fails.